# Microsoft Outlook Rest API Push rich notification with body elements

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

A rich notification payload includes the values of the properties specified in the subscription request using $select.
I can $select Subject, but cant $select Body. I receive the following response (HTTP 400):

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorUnsupportedQueryParameterSpecifiedInResourceURL",
        "message": "$top, $skip, $orderby, $select=Body,UniqueBody and $expand other than SingleValueExtendedProperties,MultiValueExtendedProperties are not supported in subscription resource Url."
    }
}
```

The documentation doesnt mention such a thing, am I missing something? Is there any other way to save a second API GET call and receive body as part of the notification payload?

Answer (score 1):

Notifications are intended to inform you of a change (create, update, delete). They are not intended to deliver an object in its entirety. It is no different than a mobile push notification as it only includes enough information to make an actionable determination.

For example, after receiving a notification of a new message in the Inbox, your app would immediately make a call to `https://graph.microsoft.com/users/{user}/messages/{id}` to retrieve the complete message.